# How to identify a PushState URL update via Console?

Tags: javascript, pushstate, history.js

Please could you advise me if there is a method of using the console/inspect-element/dev-tools to determine if a URL has been updated via PushState?

For example if I go to http://html5.gingerhost.com/ and click between "Seatle", "London" & "New York" then I know it's being updated via PushState, but how can I 'know' via the console please?

A site which is being developed is using a mix of PushState & ReplaceState and I'm keen to be able to see them in the dev tools console.

Answer (score 0):

This is for debugging purposes only, but you can override the default API with your own.

A quick and hacky way to debug history events:

```
(function(window, listenTo) {
    var history = window.history;
    // replaces default APIs with function that also logs the arguments
    listenTo.forEach(function(key) {
        var original = history[key];
        history[key] = function() {
            console.log('history.' + key, arguments);
            original.apply(history, arguments);
        };
    });
    // add a listener to the popstate event for debugging purposes
    window.addEventListener('popstate', function() {
        console.log('onpopstate', arguments);
    });
})(window, ['pushState', 'replaceState']);
```