# Angular removes the base-href for some routes

Tags: angular, .net-core

I have an issue where our Angular app removes/disregards the base-href when navigating to a certain component.
We build our app with this command:

```
ng b --prod --base-href /some-base/
```

When deployed to our Dev and Test environment, it all works as expected.
Using the Angular router, I get navigated to the correct place.

`this._router.navigate(['/register'])` -> https://test.myawesomeapp.com/some-base/register
`this._router.navigate(['/other'])` -> https://test.myawesomeapp.com/some-base/other

However there is one component where after navigation the base-href in the address bar is gone.
It manages to navigate to the correct component and the page works. But the URL in the address bar is now broken, because it does not contain the base-href.
After `this._router.navigate(['/broken'])` the URL is https://test.myawesomeapp.com/broken (where did `/some-base/` go?)

Any refresh on this page will give a 404 now because of the broken URL.
I am not sure if this is Angular routing problem or if the problem is somewhere else.

This is a .NET Core 3.1 app with an Angular SPA. Our Dev and Test environments are hosted on IIS.

Any tips on how to approach this issue will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you see what is the base-href in the generated index.html ? When you build your app, your parameters should set it to what you wrote. Check that. Also, do you reproduce 100% the issue ? What happens when you manually (writing yourself the url in the browser) to `https://test.myawesomeapp.com/some-base/broken` ? If you reproduce it by clicking on a link, can you show this link's code ? You may have an href and a router.navigate at the same time...

Comment: I checked the generated `index.html` and it was as expected.

I think you are on to something with href and router.navigate. Here's the code that runs (modified to make the names generic): https://gist.github.com/ironmaiden1212/8429139cf107df7832f4ecf840212a14

Comment: have you tried changing the `a` tag with a `button` ? So you would not have any href ?

Comment: Yes, tried with a button and I get the same behaviour. What is interesting is that with one click back in the browser or `window.history.back()` I the URL changes to the correct one. It goes from https://test.myawesomeapp.com/broken to https://test.myawesomeapp.com/some-base/broken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my issue. In the `ngOnInit()` of subcomponent of the `/broken`-page there was a call that modified the URL:

```
window.history.pushState({}, 'Placeholder', this._router.url);

// `Placeholder` was not the original text, just replaced for demo purposes
```

I used a debug trick I found in [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25531838/how-to-identify-a-pushstate-url-update-via-console) to find out if there were any changes to the history state.